# How can I change a static role to dynamic?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

How can I change the static role to dynamic?

```
def show
    @product = Product.find_by(id: params[:id])|| Product.find_by(product_id: params[:id])
    @pictures = []
    if current_user.role == "creator"
      @pictures = @product.pictures
    else
      @product.pictures.each do |picture|
        user_tags = picture.tagging.where(user_id: current_user.id) unless current_user.super_admin?
          user_tags = picture.tagging.where(user_id: 3) if current_user.super_admin?
        if user_tags.count > 0
          @pictures << picture
        end
      end
    end  
    # raise @pictures.inspect
    # raise first.users.where(role: current_user.role).inspect

  end
```

Comment: Please do not ask your question in the title

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to give certain rights to the particular role dynamically. For that you can have separate roles, and rights table in your db and roles can have multiple rights. You can have an admin screen where you can assign rights to particular role.

You can use this [gem](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) to control the ability of a role.